# How can I enforce https in Azure web app?

Tags: azure-webapps

All of the documentation I can find shows how to enforce https for Azure *App Service* by going to app-> TLS/SSL settings.  However this dashboard doesn't exist for Azure Web Apps and I don't see an equivalent way to enforce a redirect. Is this something I can only do in the web app code itself?  If it's relevant my app is a Flask app.

Note I have an SSL cert and both https and http are working fine. I just want to enforce a redirect to https when a user browses via http.

EDIT: the SSL cert is configured with a custom domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the WebApp: Settings -> Configuration -> General settings -> HTTPS only
[image]